# How prove there exist prime numbers $P_{1},P_{2},\cdots,P_{n}$ such $P_{k}\mid c+k$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> Let $c,n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that, $c>n^{n-1}$.
>
> Show that: there exist distinct prime numbers $P_{1},P_{2},\dots,P_{n}$ such that:
>
> $$P_{k}\mid c+k,k=1,2,3,\dots,n$$

My idea: if $c+k$ have greater than $n$ factor,this problem It is clear .

But other case,I can't

Comment: There are quite a few syntax / grammar / phrasing errors in your question, that make it a little difficult to understand.

Comment: You are essentially asking for a run of $n$ consecutive composite numbers. Correct?

Comment: @almagest No, a run of consecutive numbers with distinct prime divisors.

Comment: Hint: how would you pick $c$ to be sure of it being divisible by primes $p,q$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is not what it currently says (although it is constantly being edited).

Comment: @Thomas we are out of sync. I think I have understood this badly expressed problem now!

Comment: @Thomas I repeat we got out of sync. I was commenting on the primes being distinct!

Comment: The primes being distinct was always in the question, but with a different phrase, "$P_i\neq P_j$ when $i\neq j$." I edited it to say distinct instead of that long form, but it always had that in the question. @almagest

Comment: This is apparently related to [Grimm's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_conjecture) which is an open problem?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I 'feel' $c > n^{n-1}$ should make it solvable. Also see http://bit.ly/1nK3i42. It looks like Erdos and others have proved this claim for $c > n^{\frac32}(\ln n)^{-\frac12}$.

Comment: @Jeppe Ah, thanks. I feel better now having spent several hours failing to prove even the much weaker result above. But I think the one above must have a fairly simple proof. I am just being slow to see it.

Answer (score -2):

As others pointed out, what I wrote earlier did not work, and I spent several hours failing to fix it. But a correct solution turns out to be already published.

@JeppeStigNielsen [Comment under question] pointed out that this is related to Grimm's Conjecture. Grimm's Conjecture is similar but with the requirement that $c>n^{n-1}$ replaced by the requirement that the $n$ numbers $c+1,\dots,c+n$ be composite.

But in his original paper (American Mathematical Monthly 76 (1969) p1126), he proves the result above. The proof is quite short:

Consider the prime factoring of $c+1,\dots,c+n$. If $c+k$ is divisible by more than $n-1$ distinct primes, then no matter what primes are factored from the other $n-1$ numbers $c+j$ there would be a prime to factor from $c+k$. Hence we assume $c+k$ has fewer than $n$ distinct prime factors $p_{1k},\dots,p_{jk}$ (where $j<n$).

Write $$p_{1k}^{\alpha_{1k}}p_{2k}^{\alpha_{2k}}\dots p_{jk}^{\alpha_{jk}}=c+k>c>n^{n-1}$$ Since there are at most $n-1$ factors $p_{ik}^{\alpha_{ik}}$, at least one of them must be $>n$. Thus for each $c+k$ with fewer than $n$ prime factors we can choose at least one factor $p_{ik}^{\alpha_{ik}}>n$. If it were possible to choose the same prime power in two cases, say for $c+k$ and $c+j$ with $k>j$, then the smaller of the two powers $p^{\lambda}>n$ would divide the difference $c+k-(c+j)=k-j<n$, an impossibility. Thus a different prime can be associated with each number $c+k$ in all cases and the proof is complete.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Suppose we consider $n=3$ and look at the numbers $30,31,32$. If from $30$ we pick $p_1=2$ (unfortunate?) and to $31$ we use $p_2=31$, then when trying to pick a $p_3$ from $32$ we are in trouble.

Comment: What if $c+k_1$ is divisible by $p^a$ and $c+k_2$ is divisible by $q^b$ with $pq\mid k_2-k_1$? Basically, you don't know the $c+k_i$ are square-free.